# Suggestion - Hiding Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

Why hasn't the option to hide certain questions (that are for example on the first page of a Stack Exchange site you regularly frequent) implemented yet?

Answer (score 4):

This option is already implemented. You can add ignored tags, and decide if questions with the tags you add there are hidden or just greyed out.

For the browser it is available at the right sidebar:

[image: ignored tags field]

[image: ignored tags field]

---

Hiding specific questions wouldn't be really worth it (at least not for higher traffic sites). These questions would slip away from the top quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is already implemented. Go to the right side of the screen and look for the "ignored tags" field. You can then select to hide those questions altogether. Do note that this will also impact the results of your searches.

[image: screenshot of ignored tags​ list]

Comment: Think OP means the ability to hide specific questions, not by tag.

Comment: @Shadow The Burning : Exactly that. And apart from that I can not find the tag ignore field for the heck of it on my mobile. (I am using the mozilla firefox app on an android device if that matters)

Comment: The app is no longer being developed and outdated. You can only find these settings on the full site, responsiveness disabled. @Ilja

Comment: @Luuklag : I see. Thanks for the update and affirmation.

Comment: @Luuklag OP means Firefox browser app, I assume it's still developed and dated. Only SE own app has died.

Comment: @Ilja you can switch to full site any time by tapping "full site" link in the footer when on mobile, then responsive design will kick in. Think ignored tags are there, if not then you'll have to disable responsiveness as Luuklag suggested. (The ordinary mobile theme is indeed outdated and lacking most features)